# Newer programming language than Prolog for logic programming

Tags: programming-languages, paradigms, logic-programming

Is there any newer language than Prolog specialized for logical programming?

Comment: Wikipedia has a list of logic programming languages: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Logic_programming_languages

Answer (score 11):

[Mercury](http://www.mercurylang.org/) is nice and modern, and resembles prolog.

> Mercury is a new logic/functional programming language, which combines the clarity and expressiveness of declarative programming with advanced static analysis and error detection features. Its highly optimized execution algorithm delivers efficiency far in excess of existing logic programming systems, and close to conventional programming systems. Mercury addresses the problems of large-scale program development, allowing modularity, separate compilation, and numerous optimization/time trade-offs.

Comment: I would also put forward Mercury as a great logical programming language.

Also note that while Mercury's syntax might look like Prolog's, it feels more like you're programming in Haskell due to the strong type system.  Moreover if you need some typically Prolog features such as Logic Variables, Mercury does not support them.  In practice avoiding them will make your program more maintainable :-).

Disclaimer: I work on the Mercury project, observations about code maintainability are subjective and anecdotal.  Other comments are objective.

Comment: The lack of logic variables seems like a big disadvantage. Isn't that a pretty central aspect of prolog/LP?

Answer (score 7):

There is a quite promising functional logic programming language called [Curry](http://www-ps.informatik.uni-kiel.de/currywiki/). In spite of its newness it should be easy to get used to Curry if you already know Haskell and Prolog as it was directly influenced by these two languages.

> Curry combines in a seamless way
>   features from functional programming
>   (nested expressions, higher-order
>   functions, lazy evaluation), logic
>   programming (logical variables,
>   partial data structures, built-in
>   search), and concurrent programming
>   (concurrent evaluation of expressions
>   with synchronization on logical
>   variables).

Answer (score 4):

[Oz/Mozart](https://mozart.github.io/) is a Multi-paradigm programming language that supports Logic programming as one of it's features.  I've never used it so I can't say if it's good.  It certainly seems interesting though.

Disclaimer: I work on the Mercury project and would choose Mercury in a choice between Oz/Mozart and Mercury.

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget that Prolog is the host for many newer extensions which can be considered languages in their own right. In particular constraint languages like CLP(R), CLP(Q), CLP(FD). More general extensions like CHR, but also many typed approaches.

These languages usually ship as a library in an existing Prolog system. What you get in that setting is often a significantly more mature and stable implementation than from-scratch system can offer. After all, many Prolog systems are almost 30 years old.

Answer (score 4):

[Logtalk](http://logtalk.org/) is an object-oriented logic programming language that extends and leverages the Prolog language with a feature set suitable for programming in the large, focusing in code encapsulation and reuse mechanisms. It's highly portable supporting as a backend compiler most actively maintained Prolog implementations. Other noteworthy features include support for both prototypes and classes, protocols (interfaces), coinduction, component-based programming, event-driven programming, and high-level multi-threading programming. The current distribution include a large set of programming examples, programming tools, libraries, and text editors and syntax highlighters support for programming and publishing source code.

Answer (score 2):

None of the other answers has mentioned [Picat](http://picat-lang.org):

> Picat is a simple, and yet powerful, logic-based multi-paradigm programming language aimed for general-purpose applications. Picat is a rule-based language, in which predicates, functions, and actors are defined with pattern-matching rules. Picat incorporates many declarative language features for better productivity of software development, including explicit non-determinism, explicit unification, functions, list comprehensions, constraints, and tabling. Picat also provides imperative language constructs, such as assignments and loops, for programming everyday things. The Picat implementation, which is based on a well-designed virtual machine and incorporates a memory manager that garbage-collects and expands the stacks and data areas when needed, is efficient and scalable. Picat can be used for not only symbolic computations, which is a traditional application domain of declarative languages, but also for scripting and modeling tasks.

Picat looks somewhat similar to Prolog but Picat is a multi-paradigm language:

```
import util.

input_data(Tri) => 
    Lines = read_file_lines("triangle.txt"),
    Tri = new_array(Lines.length),
    I = 1,
    foreach(Line in Lines)
        Tri[I] = Line.split().map(to_integer).to_array(),
    I := I+1
    end.
```